# Function not defined though it looks defined to me

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>write html with jquery</title>
<style>
li {list-style:none;}
.green {color:#00FF00;}
.red {color:#FF0000;}
#result {font-size:3em; margin: 2em 0 0 3em;}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/write_form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="result"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function fsubmit() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("green");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    if(answer.checked == true) {
        result.className = "green"; result.innerHTML="correct!";
        } else {
        result.className = "red"; result.innerHTML="wrong";
    }
}

document.write("<header><h1>Html quiz</h1></header>");
document.write("<article><h2>What color is this?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#00ff00</h2><ul>");
document.write("<li><input type='radio' name='color1' id='red' />&nbsp;&nbsp;red</li>");
document.write("<li><input type='radio' name='color1' id='green' />&nbsp;&nbsp;green</li>");
document.write("<li><input type='radio' name='color1' id='blue' />&nbsp;&nbsp;blue</li>");
document.write("<li><input type='radio' name='color1' id='teal' />&nbsp;&nbsp;teal</li>");
document.write("<li><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' onClick='fsubmit()' /></li></ul></article>");
});
```

This is the error message I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: fsubmit is not defined write_test.html:1`

Defining the function `fsubmit()` is the first thing I do once the document is ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every function creates a new scope, even this one (at the document level)

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

so the `fsubmit` function is out of scope, remove the wrapping `$(document).ready` function, or specifically use the window namespace

```
window.fsubmit = function() {
    // your function here
}
```

or an even better idea, use proper event handlers

Comment: I'd add that writing HTML in HTML files and javascript in js files and CSS in css files is generally healthier than mixing it all up.

Comment: I thought my function was an event handler?  How would I write a proper one.

Comment: changing the scope by adding window.fsubmit = function() seems to help now I have a new error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null " I suppose it's a scope issue too.

Comment: @jimeast - The real question is, why are you writing HTML with javascript to begin with, why just not write the HTML in HTML ?

Comment: @jimeast - A proper event handler is something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/53nfA/